# How to do On click on anywhere in the page, the dropdown should be close

Tags: angularjs

if i click anywhere in the page the drop down should close, I did the code in angular.

**Html**

```
 <div class="row" ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="appInit()">
  <dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
    <dt ng-click="showDropdown=!showDropdown" ><a ng-class="myclass"  href="javascript:void(0)"><span>{{selectedRole.UserRoleDesc}}</span></a></dt><!--ng-click="myclass=!myclass"-->
    <dd>
        <ul ng-click="showDropdown=!showDropdown" style="display:block" ng-show="showDropdown">
            <li ng-repeat="user in loggedinUser" >
                <a ng-click="selectRole(user)" href="javascript:void(0)">{{user.UserRoleDesc}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: The default functionality of any drop down in HTML is to get closed when you click anywhere on the page. I guess you are generating drop down using some library. Can you post a plunker?

Comment: yes dropdown should close when you click anywhere in the page ,

but if its not happening ( not sure why , you may have to troubleshoot  ) you can register an ng-click on form and set showDropdown = false on click event